# Creating a vector using elements of another vector

Tags: r, statistics

I want to create a vector, but to do that I have to use information of another vector. I guess it's necessary to use a loop, but I don't know.

I have the vector

`n <- c(2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2, 5)`

and I have to create

`rbeta(N-12,i+1,N-i+1)`

where `i` is the ith element of n.

Comment: I forgot to say it's in R

Comment: What is `rbeta()`? Is it a function? And where is the second vector? If `rbeta()` is supposed to be the second vector, I don't understand what should be in it. Can you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: R is vectorized, so `rbeta(N - 12, n + 1, N - n + 1)` should do what you want (assuming `N` is defined and is a scalar (single) value)

Comment: Sorry. ```rbeta()``` is a function beta. It will return a number. An example would be

```d <- c(rbeta(N-12,2+1,N-2+1), rbeta(N-12,4+1,N-4+1), ..., rbeta(N-12,5-1,N-5+1))```

where ```rbeta(N-12,i+1,N-i+1)``` are real numbers

Comment: @LucasSousa but what is N?

Comment: N is a value that I have to find actually. But was trying to test how to atribute a value to it. I did 
```t <- 5000```
```N <- numeric(t)```
 and then I used N in the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `N` is a scalar value then you can use the fact that R is vectorized to get your result with

```r
rbeta(N - 12, n + 1, N - n + 1)
```

For example:

```r
n <- c(2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2, 5)
N <- 20
rbeta(N - 12, n + 1, N - n + 1)
#> [1] 0.06464326 0.41683835 0.14648202 0.22730181 0.21056577 0.17171969
#> [7] 0.28686094 0.14333501
```

Comment: N is a integer. But it depends of another number. Maybe the error it's because I don't know how to define N in a correct way.